# getting a PHP Parse error syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH)

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json, post

am trying to generate a table from json data i sent over from an angular js web app with the for each loop to build me a table so that i can send the email to users.

```
               $message = "
               </tr>
                </thead>"
                foreach ($dateils as $key=>$di) {
               " <tr >
                    <td>".$key."</td>
                    <td>".$di.typeo."</td>
                    <td>".$di.stypeo."</td>
                    <td>".$di.Diameter."</td>
                    <td>".$di.leghtn."}</td>
                    <td>".$di.amount."</td>
                </tr>"
                    }"
            </table>";
```

now thats the actual loop and here is the top

```
    $inputStream = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $data = json_decode($inputStream);

    $username = $data->username;
    $email = $data->email;
    $company= $data->company;
    $mobile = $data->mobile;
    $delivery = $data->delivery;
    $dateils = $data->details;
```

from angular am sending two json objects

```
   var transporter = []; 
    transporter.use = user;
    transporter.detail = nxt;
```

Comment: Your error is a syntax error, not logical one. You forgot a semicolon (`;`) on a line before `foreach`.

Comment: @lolbas That appears to be true, but it doesn't look like that's the only problem.

Comment: A lot of syntax errors.

Comment: @Don'tPanic true as well. Just noticed odd string start after `foreach`'s brackets.

Comment: Do you guys even notice that php code isn't inside <?php ?>

Comment: i thought i should have mentioned that the code is in inside `<?php?>`, that was a cut out from a full php file . and the foreach is in a `$message = " ..... foreach{